# Adding one more parameter in to button click func in UITableViewCell

Tags: swift

I have an `UITableView` element in my page(`ViewController`). And I use custom `UITableViewCell` for the `UITableView`.

Below code is written in `cellForRowAt` func

```
    cell.myButtonOutlet.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openDetailVC(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

and here is the `openDetailVC` func in my page(`ViewController`);

```
    @objc func openDetailVC(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
}
```

I would like to add one more parameter in to `openDetailVc` func like below.
Let's write new function with new name: `openDetailVC2`

```
@objc func openDetailVC2(_ sender: UIButton, myNewParameter: String)
{
}
```

How can I call `openDetailVC2` function in `cellForRowAt` func?
I have tried like below, but it gives an error:

```
cell.myButtonOutlet.addTarget(self, action: #selector(executeDetailVC2(_: , myNewParameter: "123456")), for: .touchUpInside)
```

(I know I can use button sender tag. But I would like to ask adding parameter in to `openDetailVC`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the selector signature. Just create a custom button, as simple as that:

```
class CustomButton : UIButton {

    var parameter : String = ""
}
...
@IBOutlet weak var btn: CustomButton!
btn.parameter = "Param value"
...
@objc public func btnClick(_ sender: Any) {
    var parameter : String = (sender as! CustomButton).parameter as? String
    ...
}
```